# select records with max(rowid) from a select with group by field

Tags: sql, postgresql, rowid

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff, gg, hh, ii, ll, mm
FROM table1
GROUP BY aa, bb, cc, dd, ee;
```

Now, i want to select for field that don't compare in group by, records with max rowid.
I'm on Postgres and so ROWID is equivalent to CTID?.

WHICH IS EQUIVALENT ROWID in postgresql?
How to do it?
Thanks

Comment: `max(rowid)` in Oracle or `max(ctid)` in Postgres makes no sense. What are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean, but you could add `max(ctid)` to the `SELECT` list.

Two caveats:

1. That does not make much sense.
2. `ctid` is quite different from Oracle's `ROWID` since PostgreSQL's row versioning works differently. After each `UPDATE`, a row can have a different `ctid`.

Comment: Oracle's rowid is actually not that different to Postgres' ctid. The rowid might change as well (although not as often as it does in Postgres). And it also does not imply any order of the rows, so using `max()` on Oracle's `rowid` makes no sense either.